# Is it safe to use the Linux Mint repository in Ubuntu?

Tags: repository, desktop-environments, mint

Let's say, for instance, I wanted to try the Cinnamon desktop in Ubuntu. Are there any dangers (in terms of stability & security) in adding the Linux Mint repository to my software sources? Should I opt instead for the ppa created especially for Ubuntu?

Comment: Sounds risky. Ubuntu and Mint aren't totally interchangeable from my experiences, but I'm not an expert on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If at all possible you should use the PPA for Ubuntu. The ppa is going to be more compatible.

If you **need** you can try to use the Mint repositories, but mixing and matching repositories can be problematic. If you do so, use pinning and install the minimal number of packages from Mint.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Comment: Since I had problems on older versions of ubuntu with PPAs, I try to avoid using them if possible. I'll follow your advice this time, though (the lesser of two evils...). Thanks.